# Parse and match text human query expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

Is there JS library to parse and match basic human-like text query expressions?
Like `word AND ( anotherword OR yetanotherword )`, or something similar.

Or maybe you know how to handle such queries, or can share a link to such info? Thanks!

Comment: You could always use a parser-generator like http://pegjs.majda.cz/

Comment: taffyDB has ANDs and ORs, among other things like LT/GTE...

Comment: Alex, thanks, I'll look at PEG.
Dan, i need to match it against a longer string. Basically search in a string/sentence.